# Permutation of String letters: How to remove repeated permutations?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, permutation

Here is a standard function to print the permutations of characters of a string:

```
void permute(char *a, int i, int n)
{
   int j;
   if (i == n)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j < n; j++) //check till end of string
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
} 

void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
```

It works fine but there is a problem, it also prints some duplicate permutations, exapmle:

if string is "AAB"

the output is:

```
AAB
ABA
AAB
ABA
BAA
BAA
```

This is having 3 duplicate entries as well.

Can there be a way to prevent this to happen?

--

Thanks

Alok Kr.

Comment: is using a std::set an undesired overhead?

Comment: Sounds like homework. You should tag it as such if it is.

Comment: Sir, Its not a homework, I am just working on some standard algorithms and i came across this question.

Also thanks for std::set as I am not that much good in c++ so didnt know about that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take notes which chars you swapped previously:

```
 char was[256];
 /*
 for(j = 0; j <= 255; j++)
    was[j] = 0;
 */
 bzero(was, 256);
 for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
 {
    if (!was[*(a+j)]) {
      swap((a+i), (a+j));
      permute(a, i+1, n);
      swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
      was[*(a+j)] = 1;
    }
 }
```

This has to be the fastest one from the entries so far, some benchmark on a "AAAABBBCCD" (100 loops):

```
native C             - real    0m0.547s
STL next_permutation - real    0m2.141s
```

Comment: Are you sure you're comparing like with like?  Once you remove the printing, and let the STL version modify a char array in situ, is your version still faster?

Comment: I won't remove printing because I have no idea what optimizations the compiler will do then. you can replace stream out with printf, and you are right that does make a huge difference. also, like vs like: my code does just *temporary* modify the char array, at the end it restores the original state.

Comment: @Kumar: sure. don't you see the logic? your code gives duplicates because it uses all duplicated characters for each position.

Comment: I am seeing the logic, but using your this piece of code is not giving me correct result. I may have done something wrong but are you sure that i dont need to change any other part of code

Comment: Is the second swap necessary?

Comment: Logically, it looks correct, but I am unable to make it work: http://codepad.org/WCSndUao. Any idea what I am doing wrong? The output just prints two strings and then is done.

Comment: @AttitudeMonger: `m` has to be local, not global.

Comment: Ah right, my bad. This works like a charm, and by far the simplest of all solutions! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Standard library has what you need:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void print_all_permutations(const string& s)
{
    string s1 = s;
    sort(s1.begin(), s1.end()); 
    do {
        cout << s1 << endl;
    } while (next_permutation(s1.begin(), s1.end()));
}

int main()
{
    print_all_permutations("AAB");
}
```

Result:

```
$ ./a.out
AAB
ABA
BAA
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach could be:

1. Presort the array.
2. This will ensure that all duplicate are now consecutive.
3. So, we just need to see the previous element which we we fixed (and permuted others)
4. if current element is same as previous, don't permute.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it the following way: First, I generate "groups" of characters (i.e. `AABBBC` yields two groups: `(AA) and (BBB) and (C)`.

First, we iterate over all distributions of `AA` onto the `n` characters. For each distribution found, we iterate over all distributions of `BBB` onto the `n-2` remaining characters (not occupied by an `A`). For each of these distributions involving `A`s and `B`s, we iterate over all distributions of `C` onto the remaining free character positions.

Comment: I really like this, because you don't generate the duplicates at all.

Comment: That was my thought as well. However, actually implementing it might become a bit cumbersome.

Comment: No, I think you can even do this in-place, and quite efficient, if you pass along an array of empty slots (if you fill a slot you move the last array entry to the respective slot in the index-array).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::set` to ensure uniqueness of the results. That is if it is C++ (because you tagged it as such).

Otherwise - go through the list of the results manually and remove duplicates.

You'll have to save the results and post-process them of course, not print immediately as you do now.

Comment: Thanks, This will help, but I would like the code to work in c too, as I have tagged it with c also.
So the other way is fine with me.

Comment: @Kumar - is it C or C++? C++ code may not work when compiled with a C compiler, C code may not work with a C++ compiler. Writing a C code doesn't make it C++, decide which language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

It would quite simple if you just think it as a problem where you need to store all the permutations for some future use.

SO you'll have an array of permuted strings.

Now think of a new problem, which is also an standard one where you need to remove the duplicates from array.

I hope that helps.

Comment: this will create `n!` permutations, then do a non-trivial filter

Answer (score 0):

@Kumar, I think what you want is something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* print all unique permutations of some text. */
void permute(int offset, int* offsets, const char* text, int text_size)
{
    int i;

    if (offset < text_size) {
            char c;
            int j;

            /* iterate over all possible digit offsets. */
            for (i=0; i < text_size; i++) {
                    c=text[i];
                    /* ignore if an offset further left points to our
                       location or to the right, with an identical digit.
                       This avoids duplicates. */
                    for (j=0; j < offset; j++) {
                            if ((offsets[j] >= i) &&
                                (text[offsets[j]] == c)) {
                                    break;
                            }
                    }

                    /* nothing found. */
                    if (j == offset) {
                            /* remember current offset. */
                            offsets[offset]=i;
                            /* permute remaining text. */
                            permute(offset+1, offsets, text, text_size);
                    }
            }
    } else {
            /* print current permutation. */
            for (i=0; i < text_size; i++) {
                    fputc(text[offsets[i]], stdout);
            }
            fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i, offsets[1024];

    /* print permutations of all arguments. */
    for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
            permute(0, offsets, argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code is C, as requested, it's pretty fast and does what you want. Of course it contains a possible buffer overflow because the offset buffer has a fixed size, but this is just an example, right?

**EDIT:** Did anyone try this out? Is there a simpler or faster solution? It's disappointing noone commented any further!

Answer (score 0):

```
void permute(string set, string prefix = ""){
    if(set.length() == 1){
            cout<<"\n"<<prefix<<set;
    }
    else{
            for(int i=0; i<set.length(); i++){
                    string new_prefix = prefix;
                    new_prefix.append(&set[i], 1);
                    string new_set = set;
                    new_set.erase(i, 1);
                    permute(new_set, new_prefix);
            }
    }
}
```

And simply use it as permute("word");

Answer (score 0):

Do not permute for same character at different position of the `string`.

In Python:

```
def unique_permutation(a, l, r):
    if l == r:
        print ''.join(a)
        return
    for i in range(l, r+1):
        if i != l and a[i] == a[l]:
            continue
        a[i], a[l] = a[l], a[i]
        unique_permutation(a, l+1, r)
        a[i], a[l] = a[l], a[i]
```

Answer (score -1):

Algorithm steps:

1. Store the given string into temporary string say "temp"
2. Remove duplicates from temp string
3. And finally call "void permute(char *a, int i, int n)" function to print all permutation of given string without duplicates

I think, this is best and efficient solution.

Comment: This affects the length of the results, which is obviously wrong.