# How can I remove duplicated permutations in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void RecPermute(string soFar, string rest)
{
    
    if (rest == "") {

        cout << soFar << endl;
    }
    else {


        for (int i = 0; i < rest.length(); i++) {
            string next = soFar + rest[i];
           
            string remaining = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i + 1);
            RecPermute(next, remaining);
            

        }
    }

}
void ListPermutations(string s) {
    RecPermute("",s);
}
int main()
{
    RecPermute("", "aab");
    return 0;

}
```

I am doing a college task, the task is to use this code to print characters permutations.
this code is doing this but repeated characters result in repeated words.
for example, if I entered "aab" the output will be:
aab
aba
aab
aba
baa
baa

Comment: Deduplicate the resulting list?

Comment: Look in to using [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes

Comment: @Casey I am not sure I understand you

Comment: 1. Collect the permutations in a vector instead of printing them; 2. Remove duplicates from the vector; 3. Print the vector elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permutation of String letters: How to remove repeated permutations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917832/permutation-of-string-letters-how-to-remove-repeated-permutations)

Answer (score 1):

This is the example source code from cppreference's [std::next_permutation entry](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation). It does exactly what you want and automatically does not include duplicates:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::string s = "aba";
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    do {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    } while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
}
```

Output:

```
aab
aba
baa
```

Comment: thank you for your effort but our professor wants us to modify the function itself.